# How to get type from attribute to execute method?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know you can I get by reflection a Type to execute a method that implements a certain interface.

System.Attribute implementation

```
    [AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Property )]
    public class ExampleAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public ExampleAttribute( string key )
        {
            Key = key;
        }

        public string Key { get; set; }

        public Type Executor { get; set; }
    }
```

Model that uses the attribute annotation (AttributeTargets.Property)

```
    public class Example
    {
        [ExampleAttribute( "property" )]
        public string Property { get; set; }

        [ExampleAttribute( "lock", Executor = typeof( LockExecutor ) )]
        public string Lock { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public interface IExecutor
    {
         object TranslateValue( object value );
    }
```

```
    public class LockExecutor: IExecutor
    {
        public object TranslateValue( object value )
        {
            var lock = value.ToString() == "LOCK";

            return lock;
        }
    }
```

I want to know how can I get by reflection the object of type IExecutor to execute the specific implementation (LockExecutor).

Comment: I think you code has code smell, describe please problem that you try to solve, I'm pretty sure that it is possible to solve problem without attributes

Comment: This is an abstraction and simplification of the requirement. I understand what you are saying because you only see a small part of the code but I think the problem requires this kind of solution. Thank you for your comment and time.

Comment: @juan if the solution from Eldar works for you just mark that as an answer. No need to put it or any modification on this back to your original post. It can lead to confusion for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it is not trying to translate something and it is just an abstraction.

```
var ex = new Example{Property = "Prop", Lock = "LOCK"};
        var type = ex.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public) // get properties
            .Select(t =>
        {
            var attr = t.GetCustomAttribute<ExampleAttribute>(); // read attribute
            var executor = attr == null ? null :attr.Executor; // it has attribute?
            IExecutor instance = null;
            if (executor != null) // attribute has executor
                instance = (IExecutor)Activator.CreateInstance(executor); // create instance
            return new
            {
            Property = t, Executor = instance
            };
        }

        ).Where(t => t.Executor != null).ToList(); // select the ones which has executor
        properties.ForEach(t =>
        {
            var val = t.Property.GetValue(ex); // get value from instance
            var translated = t.Executor.TranslateValue(val); // execute
            Console.WriteLine(translated); // dump
        }

        );
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KIhjy8)

Comment: Yeah, this is just an abstraction of the problem @Eldar. The only part that I missed was the `instance = (IExecutor)Activator.CreateInstance(executor);`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is the rational behind the requirement, but you can use this code:

```
var example = new Example() { Property = "x", Lock = "y" };
var property = example.GetType().GetProperty("Lock");
var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ExampleAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
var executer = Activator.CreateInstance(attribute.Executor);
var method = attribute.Executor.GetMethod("TranslateValue");
var result = method.Invoke(executer, new[] { example.Lock });
```

Comment: It would be simpler to cast the object returned from CreateInstance into an IExecutor and call it directly, rather than using reflection to execute TranslateValue.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yes, you are completely right. But I wanted to show how Juan can use reflection to get a method and call it.

Comment: @devquestions thank you for your response. Your solution is also right and more detailed maybe it can help others with the same problem.